# Restoring database always throwing exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, restore

I am trying to restore some database backup file into the same database. The `.bak` file is creating problem always. When I select the `.bak` file from a network drive like `"\\TestPC\ShareFolder\test.bak"` then its working correctly.

But the same `.bak` file if I select from a local drive by copying it to my pc, say `C:\TestPath\test.bak` then for every time its throwing a exception saying

> Cannot open backup device 'C:\TestPath\test.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I don't know why its throwing, I also changed the SQL Server log on from a Network drive to a local connection also. Still its not working. Can some one hint me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Web or native app?

Comment: Is the path local to Sql Server or to client PC?

Comment: @marc_s, actually the sql server is there in another pc and I have written one C# application to restore a *.bak file. Here if the .bak file is in my pc then its throwing the above exception, but if I select the same .bak file from any network drive its working fine.

Comment: @OlegDok, path local to client PC

Comment: @marc_s, is it sure? one of my team leaders says that it should work if selected from a client pc also.

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala: yes, I'm **200% sure** - see my answer....

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala - no, they are WRONG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to restore a `*.bak` file onto a machine e.g. `TESTSERVER`, then that `*.bak` file needs to be

- on a local drive of `TESTSERVER`, or:
- on a share in the network that `TESTSERVER` can reach (a "public" share)

So if you have the `*.bak` file on your local PC `MyPC`, you can **try** to do a restore from `\\MyPC\C$\ShareFolder\Backupfile.bak` and this *might or might not* work.

But you **cannot** use `C:\ShareFolder\Backupfile.bak` since that will go to the **server's** C:\ drive and look for that file - and thus you get the error message and it cannot be found.

After all: your SQL Server instance is running on `TESTSERVER` - so if that process there executes a restore from the C:\ drive, that'll be the C:\ drive **on that server machine** - **not** your local PC! If that server process on `TESTSERVER` can reach your machine, then you might use the UNC path notation to your local disk - so that *might* work.

Comment: +1, nice answer. Thank you marc_s, i will try changing the name of the drive in my code. Lets see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

So, you placed the backup file locally and then Sql Server have to read it thru or `\\YourPC\c$\TestPath\test.bak` (because sql server knows nothing about **YOUR** disk C - which is possible only in domain network and you gave to grant local admin privileges to account, the sql server runs under, or you have to share your TestPath folder and grant the sql server's account access to it

**BUT**

- If there is a Windows-domain environment, then run sql server under LocalSystem and set to the share permission to access to user DOMAINNAME\SQLSERVERPC$ where SQLSERVERPC is the name of machinesql server running on
- If there is no any domain authentication available, then you need to open Guest auth to share on backup-file machine

Comment: Ok, I agree Mr.Oleg Dok. But how to share the entire drive in my local pc to the sql server running at a remote pc

Comment: Open "My computer" shortcut, rightclick on drive C - Sharing..., voila